How to Perform Cross-Chain Swaps?
I'm trying to facilitate cross-chain swaps between Binance Smart Chain (BSC) and Polygon networks. What are the steps or tools I can use to achieve this? I'd appreciate any guidance or resources you can provide. Thanks!

You can utilise Chainlink CCIP to achieve the cross-chain transferring and swapping of tokens programmatically, which comes with the level-5 security, making it the only interoperability protocol with level-5 security.
If you would like to utilise the existing cross-chain bridges, then you can go for:

XSwap: A cross-chain protocol enabling seamless digital asset transfers across chains.

Transporter: A hyper-secure bridging app built in association with the Chainlink Foundation, with support from Chainlink Labs.


